# python not writing to file.

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
import re

req = Request("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YBn0TxzmKXI")
html_page = urlopen(req)

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page, "lxml")

tags = soup.find_all('a')

for tag in tags:
    t = tag.get('href')
    x = t.find('watch?v')
      if x > 0:
        with open("C:\BG\Output.txt", "a+") as text_file:
        text_file.write("Links are :: " % x)
```

I am trying to write to file called output.txt rather than print on screen.
Also I want to skip writing to file if contain text "google"

How can I do that
But this code is not doing it

Comment: You need to escape your backslashes in your file path i.e. `"C:\\BG\\Output.txt"` or use a raw string i.e. `r"C:\BG\Output.txt"`.

Answer (score 0):

### In regards to program not writing to file

It looks like there is an issue with your code indentation. If you move the line `text_file.write("Links are :: " % x)` one indent level futher to the right, it may solve your problem.

### In regards to checking links the link to google

You might try using `String.index()` ([linked here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.index)) to see if you can find an occurrence of `'google.com'`.

Answer (score 0):

```
if 'watch?v' in t and 'google' not in t:
    with open("Output.txt", "a+") as text_file:
        text_file.write("Links are :: " + t)
        text_file.write('\n')
```

Its simple `text` in `string` gives match `text not in` works for tag not having `google`

**Output**

```
Links are :: /watch?v=rb8K4nv2y7A
Links are :: /watch?v=rb8K4nv2y7A
.
.
```

Answer (score 0):

you have two error here:

```
text_file.write("Links are :: " % x)
```

first no `%s` where variables should be inserted, second `x` is index it should be `t`.

for performance it better to `open` file outside loop

```
with open("C:\BG\Output.txt", "a+") as text_file:
    for tag in tags:
        t = tag.get('href')
        x = t.find('watch?v')
        # if 'watch?v' in t:
        # or
        if x > 0:
            text_file.write("Links are :: %s\n" % t)
            # or
            # text_file.write("Links are :: " + t + "\n")
```